# Spring cloud stream with kafka streams binder: how to set `trusted.packages` for a Stream Processor (that's different than consumer and producer)

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a simple **stream processor** (not consumer/producer) that looks like this (Kotlin)

```
@Bean
fun processFoo():Function<KStream<FooName, FooAddress>, KStream<FooName, FooAddressPlus>> {
    return Function { input-> input.map { key, value ->
        println("\nPAYLOAD KEY: ${key.name}\n");
        println("\nPAYLOAD value: ${value.address}\n");
        val output = FooAddressPlus()
        output.address = value.address
        output.name = value.name
        output.plus = "$value.name-$value.address"
        KeyValue(key, output)
    }}
}
```

These classes `FooName`, `FooAddress` and `FooAddressPlus` are in the same package as the processor.
Here’s my config file:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
  brokers: localhost:9093

spring.cloud.stream.function.definition: processFoo

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.processFoo.applicationId: foo-processor
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processFoo-in-0:
  destination: foo.processor
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processFoo-out-0:
  destination: foo.processor.out

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
  deserializationExceptionHandler: logAndContinue
  configuration:
    default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    commit.interval.ms: 1000
```

I get this error when running the processor:

```
The class '<here_comes_package>.FooAddress' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. 
If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. 
If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
```

What is the best way to set trusted packages to everything when using  **Kafka Streams Binder Stream Processor**? (no consumer/producer but stream processor)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Kafka The class is not in the trusted packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688924/spring-kafka-the-class-is-not-in-the-trusted-packages)

Comment: @jokarls Thanks. That was one the things I have tried before but I have a stream processor and in that answer they are using a consumer and producer separately. In that case they either set the consumer/producer props in the config (spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages) or they have their consumer/producer factories where they set the deserializer. Since I have a stream processor, there's no consumer nor producer props or factories that I can set, but I might be wrong about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set arbitrary configuration properties (Kafka streams properties, properties used by the serdes, etc) under `...binder.configuration`:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
```

Comment: That code is useful, but your answer would be better if you could add a description on how this code fragment addresses the problem

Comment: Thanks @gary-russel. As asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64516217/spring-cloud-stream-with-kafka-stream-binder-using-topologytestdriver-i-get-the?noredirect=1#comment114116760_64516217
how can I set this property in tests when using `TopologyTestDriver`?
I can't make it work when setting this porperty in TopologYTestDriver creation. Thanks

Comment: @gary-russell this doesn't work (anymore), I see the following: `2021-04-12 13:46:55.767 [main] WARN  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - The configuration 'spring.json.trusted.packages' was supplied but isn't a known config.`

Comment: That is just a bogus warning coming from the kafka Consumer about a property it doesn't recognize. In fact it proves that the property **is** being set correctly - the same properties are passed into the serde in its `configure()` method. If you are having problems, ask a new question showing code, configuration, versions, logs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring Cloud Stream binder for Kafka, adding below properties has resolved deserialization issue with trusted packages

spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*