# Testing Spring cloud stream with kafka stream binder: using TopologyTestDriver I get the error of "The class is not in the trusted packages"

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, spring-cloud-stream

I have this simple **stream processor** (not a consumer/producer) using kafka streams binder.

```
@Bean
fun processFoo():Function<KStream<FooName, FooAddress>, KStream<FooName, FooAddressPlus>> {
    return Function { input-> input.map { key, value ->
        println("\nPAYLOAD KEY: ${key.name}\n");
        println("\nPAYLOAD value: ${value.address}\n");
        val output = FooAddressPlus()
        output.address = value.address
        output.name = value.name
        output.plus = "$value.name-$value.address"
        KeyValue(key, output)
    }}
}
```

I'm trying to test it using the TopologyTestDriver:

```
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
        classes = [Application::class, FooProcessor::class]
)
class FooProcessorTests {
    var testDriver: TopologyTestDriver? = null
    val INPUT_TOPIC = "input"
    val OUTPUT_TOPIC = "output"

    val inputKeySerde: Serde<FooName> = JsonSerde<FooName>()
    val inputValueSerde: Serde<FooAddress> = JsonSerde<FooAddress>()
    val outputKeySerde: Serde<FooName> = JsonSerde<FooName>()
    val outputValueSerde: Serde<FooAddressPlus> = JsonSerde<FooAddressPlus>()

    fun getStreamsConfiguration(): Properties? {
        val streamsConfiguration = Properties()
        streamsConfiguration[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "TopologyTestDriver"
        streamsConfiguration[StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "dummy:1234"
        streamsConfiguration[JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES] = "*"
        streamsConfiguration["spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages"] = "*"
        return streamsConfiguration
    }

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val builder = StreamsBuilder()
        val input: KStream<FooName, FooAddress> = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC, Consumed.with(inputKeySerde, inputValueSerde))
        val processor = FooProcessor()
        val output: KStream<FooName, FooAddressPlus> = processor.processFoo().apply(input)
        output.to(OUTPUT_TOPIC, Produced.with(outputKeySerde, outputValueSerde))
        testDriver = TopologyTestDriver(builder.build(), getStreamsConfiguration())
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        try {
            testDriver!!.close()
        } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
            // https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647 causes exception when executed in Windows, ignoring it
            // Logged stacktrace cannot be avoided
            println("Ignoring exception, test failing in Windows due this exception:" + e.localizedMessage)
        }
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    fun testOne() {
        val inputTopic: TestInputTopic<FooName, FooAddress> =
                testDriver!!.createInputTopic(INPUT_TOPIC, inputKeySerde.serializer(), inputValueSerde.serializer())
        val key = FooName()
        key.name = "sherlock"
        val value = FooAddress()
        value.name = "sherlock"
        value.address = "Baker street"
        inputTopic.pipeInput(key, value)
        val outputTopic: TestOutputTopic<FooName, FooAddressPlus> =
                testDriver!!.createOutputTopic(OUTPUT_TOPIC, outputKeySerde.deserializer(), outputValueSerde.deserializer())
        val message = outputTopic.readValue()

        assertThat(message.name).isEqualTo(key.name)
        assertThat(message.address).isEqualTo(value.address)
    }
}
```

When running it, I get this error in line `inputTopic.pipeInput(key, value)`

*The class '*package*.FooAddress' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).*

Any ideas on how to solve this? Setting those properties in `getStreamsConfiguration()` is not helping. Please note that this is a stream processor, not a consumer/producer.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot @GaryRussell. I will check from my other question. Btw, thanks for the awesome spring cloud stream framework

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to make it work, probably I'm doing something wrong so I would really appreciate your guidance @GaryRussell
In my `getStreamsConfiguration` method I have added:
`streamsConfiguration["spring.cloud.streams.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.spring.json.trusted.packages"] = "*"` but still the test fails due `is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]`. Thank you!

Comment: I will look into why it doesn't work with the test driver - it knows nothing about Spring to adding the spring property there won't help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GaryRussell. I can provide a git repo with the code if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Kafka creates the Serde itself, it applies the properties by calling `configure()`.

Since you are instantiating the Serde yourself, you need to call `configure()` on it passing in the map of properties.

That's how the trusted packages property gets propagated to the deserializer.

Or, you can call `setTrustedPackages()` on the deserializer.

Comment: OMG it works! Can't really say how grateful I am. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how do I call `setTrustedPackages()` on the deserializer? I don't have access to it, do I? I have only the serdes that I create. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a constructor where you can provide the pre-configured (de)serializers `public JsonSerde(JsonSerializer<T> jsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer<T> jsonDeserializer)`. Or, you can cast the value returned by `deserializer()` to a `JsonDeserializer<?>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips @GaryRussell, followed the procedure with the answers.

Answer (score 1):

So, for completeness, here's how the code looks when configuring the serde as @GaryRussell suggests:

```
private fun getStreamsConfiguration(): Properties? {
    // Don't set the trusted packages here since topology test driver does not know about Spring
    val streamsConfiguration = Properties()
    streamsConfiguration[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "TopologyTestDriver"
    streamsConfiguration[StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "dummy:1234"
}
```

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    val builder = StreamsBuilder()
    // Set the trusted packages for all serdes
    val config = mapOf<String, String>(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES to "*")
    inputKeySerde.configure(config, true)
    inputValueSerde.configure(config, false)
    outputKeySerde.configure(config, true)
    outputValueSerde.configure(config, false)
}
```

And the rest of the code remains as described in the question. All credit to @GaryRusell.