# Spring boot Kafka Consumer Error deserializing key/value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm a newbie with Kafka I have created 2 projects, the first project as a Producer, and the second as a Consumer.

**Note**
In both projects, if I create a **Model** or **DTO** under the same package (**example: com.stackoverflow.model**), it works, but it doesn't work if I created a model under a different package name as below:

- The producer defines the package **com.stackoverflow.model**
- The consumer defines the package **com.stackoverflow.dto**

**Error logs:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition txn-hub-master-0 at offset 4. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.stackoverflow.dto.Demo' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.stackoverflow.mode, com.stackoverflow.mode.model.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:126) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:100) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
```

KafkaConsumerConfig Class

```
public Map<String, Object> propsStringObjectMap() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return props;
    }
```

```
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = this.propsStringObjectMap();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,  StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

```
  @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

KafkaProducerConfig Class

```
public Map<String, Object> propsStringObjectMap () {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }
```

```
@Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(this.propsStringObjectMap());
    }
```

```
@Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this might help .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688924/spring-kafka-the-class-is-not-in-the-trusted-packages

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using StringDeserializer rather than JsonDeserializer?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, no specific reason, and I had changed to JsonDeserializer, it also works.

Comment: Hi @Umeshwaran, the link that you had mentioned above help me to solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Theara Glad it helped